# Import CSV to Excel - automatically "Text to columns" and "insert table"

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'd like to open my CSV (comma-delimited) file on Excel 2010 and automagically convert text to columns and then select all active cells and insert table with headers.

Is it possible to add a button to my ribbon that would do all this for me?

I quite often work with CSV files with different sizes and I find it to be bit of a pain to do this manually each time.

Comment: Start by switching the macro recorder on, opening and storing your file and closing the macro recorder.  Study the saved macro.  For your working macro, parameters are going to be: name of file, destination sheet, location, etc.  Are you going to use InputBox or the file dialog?  Bits of your question have already been asked and answered so look through recent questions.  Tag `excel-vba` will be the most relevant.  Discover as much as you can yourself before coming back with questions on any remaining issues.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for this, but I just ran across the question...

This is for selecting specific files from a picker:

```
Sub OpenCSV()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fd.Show
    For Each fileItem In fd.SelectedItems
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
            fileItem _
            , Origin:=65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
            xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Next
End Sub
```

This will open all CSV files in a chosen folder:

```
Sub OpenCSVFolder()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fd.Show
    For Each folderItem In fd.SelectedItems
        fileItem = Dir(folderItem & "\" & "*.csv")
        While fileItem <> ""
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
                folderItem & "\" & fileItem _
                , Origin:=65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
                xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
                Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            fileItem = Dir
        Wend
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that these files are set to `Tab Delimited` - change the delimiter by updating the `Tab:=True` or `Comma:=False` parameters.